# Symfony2 - Differentiating between the way a user logged in

Tags: php, security, symfony, symfony-forms

**Software/Bundles:** Symfony2 + FOS User+FacebookBundle

**The Problem:**

A user can login via the *"Login with Facebook"*-Button and a regular *"Login Form"* (Standard Login Form).
The task is to **differentiate which login** method **the user used**, **in the login process**, so that custom logic can be executed, based on which way the user took to access the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there will be no other way than to extend the *bundles (not components)* login action to save a custom flag into user session.
if your custom logic is just redirect the user to a different action then you will need only to alter the redirect logic of the login actions in your used bundles

you can check the official bundle documentation on how to do it:

[Overriding Default FOSUserBundle Controllers](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md)